# opening and writing commands to a cmd from text box

Tags: c#, process, cmd

I am trying to open a `cmd.exe` and write in it from multiple text boxes. But I can't get anything to show up but the cmd:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd", "perl "+ textBox5.Text + textBox4.Text + textBox6.Text + textBox7.Text + textBox8.Text + textBox9.Text);
```

Comment: I've posted an answer, hope it helps ;-)

Comment: try doing a google search on `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start expamples` there are plenty of them out there here is one https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjv3djnmfDKAhXLSCYKHQLhCDYQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.codeproject.com%2FArticles%2F4272%2FUsing-Diagnostics-Process-to-start-an-external-app&usg=AFQjCNFycjpPWKQXly90O4K90PcypfT_2Q&bvm=bv.113943164,d.cWw

Comment: @Waypast: If my answer helped you please give me an upvote - thx.

Comment: Haven't got the reputation yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to start either `cmd` with the option `/c` and pass every following data by using `"` like `cmd /c "perl ...` or you can just start `perl` as the process and pass everything else as an argument.

You can find a detailed documentation about the parameters [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490880.aspx).

So you would have to change your code to either

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd","/c \"perl "+ textBox5.Text + textBox4.Text + textBox6.Text + textBox7.Text + textBox8.Text + textBox9.Text + "\"");
```

or

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("perl", textBox5.Text + textBox4.Text + textBox6.Text + textBox7.Text + textBox8.Text + textBox9.Text);
```

In addition: You could improve the readability and performance of your code by NOT using `+` in combination with `strings`. If you would use a [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/System.Text.StringBuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you could change your code to the following one:

```
StringBuilder arguments = new StringBuilder();
arguments.Append(textBox5.Text);
arguments.Append(textBox4.Text);
arguments.Append(textBox6.Text);
arguments.Append(textBox7.Text);
arguments.Append(textBox8.Text);
arguments.Append(textBox9.Text);

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("perl", arguments.ToString());
```

Comment: A downvote without explanation is always great ... :-(

Answer (score 0):

You should have to add the parameter /c or /k to the beginning of your params

http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html